# How to model Tasks and sub-tasks for a LMS model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Beginner here, I am making a LMS application where I have a Course model, a Task model and a sub-task model. The relationship are as follows:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :subtasks
end

class Subtask < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
end
```

Basically, If I have a Course named Rails 5 then the structure should look like something as given below:

```
Course Rails 5
  Task Devise
    Sub-task 1
    Sub-task 2
    Sub-Task 3
  Task Authorization
    Sub-task 1
    Sub-task 2
    Sub-Task 3
    Sub-Task 4
```

I have two questions here:

1) Have I associated my models correctly or do I need to do something else in order to achieve the above structure?

2) If this is correct then do I have to use nested attributes to add task and subtasks inside course creating form?

Comment: Probably, should be posted in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This question isn't well-suited for SO, simply because the answer is "yes" and "yes". You should post any issues you may have after you've implemented said form.

Comment: You could also add `has_one :course, through: :task` to Subtask. Regarding the nested attributes, you don't strictly speaking have to do this. It is certainly a popular way to do it (see the [Nested Forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) section of the Rails Guides) but not the only way. You could, for example, build your forms "by hand" (without Rails form helpers).

Comment: @maxpleaner How will the association you provided prove beneficial to me? I mean what will be it's usage?

Comment: @SarahJones it'd just be so you could say `@subtask.course` instead of `@subtask.task.course` ... not a big deal